# White space above the body when I use "height:100vh"

Tags: html, css, viewport

I've got a basic HTML document setup and I want the div to have the height of the view port. But as soon as I add `height:100vh` to the `.main` div there's a gap above the body and there's a vertical scroll bar

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main_text">
            <h1>Hey there! I'm <span class="yellow">Gautham SK</span>, a digital designer &amp; web developer.</h1>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end container -->
</div> <!-- end main -->
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}



.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

.nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
/*  margin-top: 75px;*/
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav ul li {
    margin-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav ul li a, .nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffde00;
    transition: 0.2s color;
}

.nav ul li a.active {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffde00;
}

/* MAIN SECTION */

.main {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") center center no-repeat;    
    background-size: cover;
}

.main, .main .container {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main_text {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main_text h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 45px;
}

span.yellow {
    color: #ffde00;
}
```

I've also got a normalize.css linked to this document. I tried to remove the padding and margin for all the elements but that doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

Yay! Found the solution. Here's what I did:

- Removed the margin for the nav and it's children and replaced it with a top padding to get the desired look.
- Changed the height of the `main_text` to 80%.

If you've got a better solution, let me know!

Comment: What you wanted to do?

Comment: I want to make the `main` section fit the height of the viewport. But when I do that, there's a gap on top with a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple test, set `padding: 1px` on `body`. If the gap goes away read: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The body is now pulled to the top with a padding of 1px around it, but all the tags inside the `body` tag still has the gap on the top. Eg: The `main` tag still has the gap on the top, even though there isn't any margin or padding applied to it.

Comment: So there's some margin or padding to inner element who create this problem. Try to look at link i've passed. It's like 23 hours since i slept and i've some problems now to figure out your error :D

Comment: I'll try to see it after some hour of sleep. Pay attention not only to margin applied at the single element but also to the one applied at inside elements. Try to remove them all and create them one by one to see the one who create the error.

Comment: Haha. That's fine. I'll surely read that. When you're free could you look into the code? I really need to complete this project. :)

Comment: Update: When I got rid of the `nav` completely everything seems to have worked. But I want the nav to have a top margin of 75px. What do I do?

Comment: Try to put the margin to ul. Or use a padding on the nav instead of a margin. The result should normally be the same.

Comment: Perfect! I'll go to sleep :D Have a nice day! @Armilan1987 on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the white spacing under the image on my phone preview. But for some reason instead of having the height:100vh; I changed to height:110vh; and the white spacing went away and fit the phone screen.

here is the csspart

```
.background_sv{
 position: absolute;
 height: 110vh; 
 width: auto;
}
```

White spacing image here before having it `height:110vh;`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp4DE.jpg

After fixing it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGcOg.jpg

it fit the screen.

Phone is pretty long . Song Xperia 10 ii
maybe because of that but I didnt try it out on any other device